# Force browser to ignore the if-modified-since HTTP field

Tags: http, browser

I am trying to reload a page. So, when the page is loaded for the first time I download the whole HTML and the embedded objects. But the next time I request the same page the browser sends an if-modified-since field along with the GET request. The server replies with a Not Modified response for the main HTML and all the embedded objects. The page I am trying to access here changes rarely (once in a year perhaps). How can I force the browser to forget the if-modified-since field and download the page every time from scratch. No restrictions on which browser you choose as long as it allows me to do what I want.

Comment: Why do you want this? It sounds like you have a problem, but propose a work around here. Why do you want to reload a page if it doesn't change? Count the number of visits on the server side?

Comment: @Marcel: I can't explain the reason here. It will be too much of a distraction.

Comment: But do you want a server-side solution or something on the client-side? Using JavaScript you can add a random number to the query string and the browser will get a fresh copy.

Comment: @Marcel: I want a client side solution.

Comment: Using JavaScript, I suppose? Or using a static link you added to your page using a server-side script?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a shift-reload helps in that case.